# Monotouch equivalent of the "transitionWithView" method of the UIViewController iOS 5.0 class

Tags: binding, uiviewcontroller, ios5, xamarin.ios, transition

I cannot find the monotouch equivalent of the "transitionWithView" method of the UIViewController iOS 5.0 class.

When I search in the Rosetta docs ( http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html ) I find this:

```
Selector: transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:    
Method: void Transition (UIView fromView, UIView toView, double duration, UIViewAnimationOptions options, [NullAllowed] NSAction completion);

Selector: transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:    
Method: void Transition (UIView withView, double duration, UIViewAnimationOptions options, [NullAllowed] NSAction animation, [NullAllowed] NSAction completion);
```

Is this documentation outdated? Because when I try such method in MonoDevelop I cannot find any overload for "Transition". It seems that the only implementation in MonoTouch is a binding to the "transitionFromView" selector. The signature is also wrong: it doesn't accept nulls and it requires an additional UICompletitionHandler parameter. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I did't find it in my UIView instances because the method was STATIC, but this was nowhere indicated in the Rosetta docs. I hope this will be fixed in the final rosetta documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The first selector you're finding with the Rosetta is part of [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) not [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

> Is this documentation outdated?

No. While the Rosetta is not (yet) part of the official documentation it is up to date and the second selector maps to the right binding method.

> Because when I try such method in MonoDevelop I cannot find any overload for "Transition".

I did not have any issue using MonoDevelop code completion for `Transition` on an `UIViewController` instance (note that it's not an overload - just a *normal* method).

> The signature is also wrong: it doesn't accept nulls and it requires an additional UICompletitionHandler parameter.

Please report missing bindings or errors in binding in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com so they will be tested/fixed asap (and that will also give you a notification when the fix is made).

> Is there something I'm missing?

Ensure you are using an `UIViewController` object (e.g. not an `UIView`) when trying to use the `Transition` method. Also make sure you have the latest MonoTouch (5.0+) and MonoDevelop.